# Regex capture only numbers inside specific tag

Tags: java, regex

I have the following text

```
<msgText>H3ll0World</msgText><msgText>HelloWorld</msgText><otherTagWithNumbers>456</otherTagWithNumbers>
```

I need to retrive only the numbers ( `[\d]` ) inside the tag `<msgText>` in order to replace them. In this case the regex would return 3 and 0.

What I have so far:

```
(<msgText>)([\s\S]*?)(<\/msgText>)
```

[Here](https://regex101.com/r/0zGJMj/3/) I have an example of this situation.

Comment: Try this [`\d+(?=(?:(?!<\/?\w+>).)*<\/msgText>)`](https://regex101.com/r/0zGJMj/4)

Comment: Just open the xml as xml and go through its contents.

Comment: you should consult [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). where's the code where you tried something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd like to use a positive lookahead to look but not consume:

```
\d+(?=(?:(?!<\/?\w+>).)*<\/msgText>)
```

Breakdown:

- `\d+`    Match any number
- `(?=`    That is followed by

  - `(?:(?!<\/?\w+>).)*` A tempered greedy token to match anything but not
    pass over tags
  - `<\/msgText>`    Up to a closing tag
- `)` End of positive lookahead

Above is a strict match but there is a short way to achieve the same under some circumstances:

```
\d+(?=[^<]*<\/msgText>)
```

[Live demo](https://regex101.com/r/qlCWlC/1)

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to parse XML with regex, [again...](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/2707792)

But maybe this works on some extremely restricted subset of XML that you are dealing with:

```
(\d+)(?=\w*<\/msgText>)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/0zGJMj/6).

Comment: Thanks bro. I'm not trying to parse a XML, I just want to replace numbers inside a specific tag. Thanks again!

Comment: @JoabeLucena Yeah, I understand that, it was just the obligatory disclaimer that XML is not regular, like for any other "regex + (X/HT)ML" question ;) Glad that you could solve your problem despite all the theoretical obstacles xD